# Print XML field values to CSV

Tags: xml, bash, sed, terminal, grep

I have a directory with loads of XML files that are not formatted in the exact same way but the ones I am after contain the 3 same required fields. I need to know the SNPID of each library as they must be unique. For this I need to list each and their ID value.

Firstly I need to only get results from files containing the value="Kontakt" in the "PoweredBy" field.
Then for each I need the Name, SNPID and RegKey to print into a 3 column CSV. eg. Mystica | 547 | Best Service - Mystica

The XML files are like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<ProductHints spec="1.0.16">

  <Product version="2">
    <UPID>70026fd5-8f6f-429e-b891-12c2f94bc566</UPID>
    <Name>Mystica</Name>
    <Type>Content</Type>
    <NKSEnabled minVersion="1.1.0.0">true</NKSEnabled>
    <Relevance maxVersion="1.0.9.0" minVersion="1.0.0.0">
      <Application minVersion="5.0.0.0" nativeContent="true">kontakt</Application>
    </Relevance>
    <Relevance minVersion="1.1.0.0">
      <Application minVersion="5.8.0.0" nativeContent="true">kontakt</Application>
      <Application minVersion="2.6.5.0">maschine</Application>
      <Application minVersion="1.8.2.0">kkontrol</Application>
    </Relevance>
    <PoweredBy>Kontakt</PoweredBy>
    <Visibility maxVersion="1.0.9.0" minVersion="1.0.0.0" target="Standalone">1</Visibility>
    <Company>Best Service</Company>
    <AuthSystem>RAS2</AuthSystem>
    <SNPID>547</SNPID>
    <RegKey>Best Service - Mystica</RegKey>
    <Icon>bestservice</Icon>
    <ProductSpecific>
      <HU>496B8CF4F8B1402C4A6650214DF2514C</HU>
      <JDX>C9A2B6D9549FD159D8A3CFF054AAE934C2AC849EC74827847288DF07577A8F22</JDX>
      <Visibility type="Number">3</Visibility>
    </ProductSpecific>
  </Product>

</ProductHints>
```

I've tried

```
Computer:~ user$ cd /Library/Application\ Support/Native\ Instruments/Service\ Center 
Computer:Service Center

        while read -r Name SNPID RegKey
do
    echo "+++++++++++++++++++"
    echo "Name:  ${Name}"
    echo "SNPID: ${SNPID}"
    echo "RegKey: ${RegKey}"
awk -F '[<>]' '{if (FNR%2==1) {printf "%s: ",$3} else {print $3}}'
done
```

but the results are inconsistent (I know bash isn't great for parsing XML but the requirements are pretty basic).

```
find -name "*.xml" | xargs cat | tr -d "\n" | sed 's/<\/Name>/\n/g' | sed 's/<\/SNPID>/\n/g' | sed 's/<\/RegKey>/: /g' | sed 's/<[^>]*>//g' | egrep "Name:|SNPID:|RegKey:" | sed 's/Name: /---\nName: /g'
```

also results in error: find: illegal option -- n

Any BASH wizards out there that can help me please? (If possible I would prefer to use terminal without installing other things) Thanks

Comment: Welcome Mantissa, very good job presenting the question. Well fomratted. With good sample data and sharing your attempt as well.

Comment: I believe `xmllint` is better suited for reading XML files.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -sE '/^\s*<(Name|SNPID|PoweredBy|RegKey)>(.*)<\/\1>\s*$/{s//\1:\2/;H}
         $!d;g;/PoweredBy:Kontakt/!d
         s/Name:([^\n]*)(.*)/\2\n\1/
         s/SNPID:([^\n]*)(.*)/\2|\1/
         s/RegKey:([^\n]*)(.*)/\2|\1/
         s/.*\n//' file ...
```

Use the options `-s` to treat each input file separately and `-E` to simplify regexps.

Using alternation, extract the required fields into the hold buffer.

At the end of the file if the `PoweredBy` field does not contain `Kontakt` no further processing is required.

Otherwise, format the fields in the hold buffer into the required format and print the result.

Answer (score 1):

Highly recommeded: Don't try to parse xml with anything other than a proper xml parser. For that you can use either xmlstarlet [edited to reflect @Reino's comment below:

```
xml sel -T -t -m "//ProductHints//Product[PoweredBy="Kontakt"]" -v //SNPID/. --nl -v //Name/. --nl -v //RegKey/. --nl your_file.xml
```

or, even simpler, xidel:

```
xidel your_file.xml -e '//ProductHints//Product[PoweredBy="Kontakt"]//(Name,SNPID,RegKey)'
```

Output (based on the sample xml in your question) should be:

```
547
Mystica
Best Service - Mystica
```

Comment: You forgot about the "PoweredBy"-node condition and the output format: `-e 'ProductHints/Product[PoweredBy="Kontakt"]/join((Name,SNPID,RegKey)," | ")'`.

Comment: @Reino Correct - fixed the answer to reflect that, though I didn't adopt the `join()` method since I don't believe OP asked for that.

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. Locating required files using `find` and `grep`

```
 grep -l "PoweredBy>Kontakt" $(find . -name "*.xml")
```

Validate you get the correct file list.

#### 2. Extracting data, and formating data from required files using `awk`

This `awk` script, process only the required files one by one.

```
 awk -F"[><]" '
   $2 == "Name" {ret = $3 " | "}
   $2 == "SNPID" {ret = ret $3 " | "}
   $2 == "RegKey" {print ret $3}
 ' $(grep -l "PoweredBy>Kontakt" $(find . -name "*.xml"))
```

An alternative using `awk` without `grep` command.

```
 awk -F"[><]" '
   $2 == "PoweredBy" && $3 != "Kontakt" {nextfile} 
   $2 == "Name" {ret = $3 " | "}
   $2 == "SNPID" {ret = ret $3 " | "}
   $2 == "RegKey" {print ret $3}
 ' $(find . -name "*.xml")
```

Comment: Both snippets return error - find: illegal option -- t
usage: find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] [-f path] path ... [expression]
       find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] -f path [path ...] [expression]

Comment: try to omit `-type f` . probably not supported in your machine. `grep -l "PoweredBy>Kontakt" $(find -name "*.xml")`

Comment: Updated answer accordingly. Omit `-type f`

Comment: unfortunately doesn't work for me - getting the error "find: illegal option -- n". I'm stuck on osx 10.14.06 (thanks to some 3rd party audio plugins) and have Xcode 11.1 installed but there seems to be some libraries missing perhaps? I also updated "brew install findutils" but no dice. My BASH version is 3.2.57(1).Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: suggesting try `find . -name "*.xml"` (notice `.` after find)  . In some `find` version providing the base directory is mandatory. In Linux omitting the base directory default to current directory.

Comment: Every `find` since the dawn of time has supported `-type f`.

Comment: Looking into OSX documentation here: https://ss64.com/osx/find.html `-type f` is supported and base pathname is optional. So probably your OSX machine needs some repair.